# disable other buttons using e.target.id

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, redux, material-ui

- I have ten expansion panels.
- on click of one button in one expansion panel I need to disable other buttons in other expansion panel
- but the problem is when I try to target with an id I, its not returning e.target.id
- it just returns as the value passed.
- can you tell me how to fix it.
- providing my sandbox and code snippet below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-zi66l

```or-tag-here
diableOtherButtons = e => {
    console.log("diableOtherButtons e--->", e);
  };


  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    console.log("get started *8888888888888888888888888888888888888888888888");
    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <ExpansionPanel>
          <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
            <Typography className={classes.heading}>first</Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelSummary>
          <ExpansionPanelDetails>
            <Typography>
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
              Suspendisse malesuada lacus ex, sit amet blandit leo lobortis
              eget.
              <Typography>
                <Button
                  onClick={e => {
                    this.diableOtherButtons("s", "d");
                  }}
                  variant="outlined"
                  color="primary"
                  size="small"
                  // className={classes.button}
                >
                  button click
                </Button>
              </Typography>
            </Typography>
          </ExpansionPanelDetails>
```

Comment: I dont see where you target the 'other' buttons.. why not give them all a class ,reset all with that class and activate only the clicked one?

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. But you should look for the button under e.nativeTarget

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).